# How do I add tests to an existing JUnit in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I added some methods in a class which was already under a JUnit coverage.
Now I want to extend the existing JUnit with some tests to validate the new methods.

I want to know if there is a way to do this via GUI, without installing any other plugin like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7177457/eclipse-how-to-update-a-junit-test-file-with-newly-added-method-in-the-source-f) advices.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why don't you want to just add methods to the class? What do you mean by "via GUI"?

Comment: @JonSkeet When you create a new JUnit you are asked which methods you want to test in a nice GUI. I'd like to have the same GUI where I can see the methods not covered and select which to add. It's not a must but it would be nice to have.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "a new JUnit" but I normally just write code. It really doesn't take that long to add methods by hand - or if it does, it's worth improving your typing speed. Note that if a GUI is encouraging you write write one test method method, you should resist that. For all but the most primitive methods, there are multiple scenarios you should be testing.

Comment: @JonSkeet the question is only because eclipse gives you a GUI to create a JUnit and I was wondering if the same tool had also a way to edit existing units. If not so, I have no problem to do it by hand.

Answer (score 1):

Well, without the plugin, you always have the manual method.

Just add the test methods to your JUnit and annotate them with `@Test`. This will allow JUnit to recognize the method as a test and execute it. In these newly added methods, you should invoke the newly added methods of your class and check their behavior.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but this violates the "via GUI" constraint ;-)